# Is my laptop fast enough to run WIndows 10?

Tags: windows-10, performance, windows-10-upgrade

I'm thinking about updating from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. Before I do that, I would like to know if my laptop will run as fast as it does with Windows 8?
Here my specs:

```
Model: Lenovo S210 Touch Laptop
Processor: Intel Pentium Processor Dual-Core 987 1.5 GHz w/ Intel HD Graphics
Chipset: Intel HM76 Express
Memory: 8GB PC3-10600 1333MHz DDR3L
Storage: 500GB SSHDD 2.5" SATA 6Gb/s 5400RPM
```

Thank you for your feedback.

EDIT: Thank you all for your answers. I updated to Windows 10 and everything works, no problems at all. The performance is better than in Windows 8.1.

Comment: "with an acceptable performance" is very subjective, and also performance heavily depends on usage.

Comment: Since being edited to *"will [it] run as fast... as Windows 8"* it doesn't really sound opinion-based anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Windows 10 is build on the core of Windows 8 where they wanted to optimize windows, I can safely say, if your laptop runs windows 8, it will run windows 10 too. The same applies for windows 7. If it runs windows 7, it runs windows 10.

The only concern here is when you have a very old pc running windows 7 or you have exclusive hardware. In these cases, it may be that not all drivers are ready for windows 10 in which case upgrading may not be wishful. That is not the case for your laptop though.

I found that windows 10 performance is better than 8 and 7 as the memory footprint is smaller.

Upgrading your installation should take care of all driver issues and should give you the same performance or slightly better as you already had. If you want to get a faster experience, you can always reset your installation to a clean one after the installation has been done by searching for "reset" in the start menu and choosing for "Reset this pc."

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, based on the [Official Requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-10-specifications#sysreqs)

Outlined here:

Processor:
1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster processor or SoC

RAM:
2 gigabyte (GB) for 32-bit and 64-bit

Hard disk space:
16 GB for 32-bit OS 20 GB for 64-bit OS

Graphics card:
DirectX 9 or later with WDDM 1.0 driver **Suggest checking your DirectX version**

Display:
800x600

Answer (score -1):

you may need to turn off some animations and other graphics features.  your specifications are well above the minimum requirements.  the only concern I have is the integrated graphics but after a quick review of the spec sheet, I changed my mind.

before you install windows 10, ensure that you have all the drivers you need on a USB stick.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/windows-10-specifications